# Download monthly bank statements using Plaid API

Tags: plaid

I am automating the process of downloading monthly bank statements from a few different banking portals, all from banks that support Plaid.

Is there a way to use the Plaid API to download monthly bank statements? I've looked through their docs and don't see much related to monthly statements besides [last_statement_issue_date](https://plaid.com/docs/api/products/#liabilities-get-response-last-statement-issue-date_liabilities).

Answer (score 1):

Like, a copy of the statement as a PDF? No. Plaid's API can be used to provide the same kind of information that you would find on a statement (transaction history, balance history, address, etc.), but it doesn't literally provide statements.

Answer (score 0):

For those visisting in 2023, Plaid seems to have a new product offering [Statements](https://plaid.com/docs/statements/) which is currently in beta